# Visual Studio Team Services: Build Error (Assembly reference cannot be resolved)

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a project on Visual Studio Team Services that builds just fine locally, and get the following exceptions:

```
Code Analysis detected errors.  See Code Analysis results window or log file for details.
CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'Acme.Web': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
CA0058 : The referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be found. This assembly is required for analysis and was referenced by: C:\a\bin\Acme.Web.dll.
```

I looked through all .csproj files and NuGet packages files manually and fail to find any reference to Microsoft.Owin (2.0.0.0) - all projects seem to reference the correct assembly 2.1.0.0.

Does anyone have a hint where I could continue searching or has anybody experienced a similar issue with VS Team Services CI?

Comment: Welcome to my world. I waste so much time fixing these issues and I still have no idea how I do it.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am running into the same issue. Not sure if we are experiencing the same problem, but at least the symptoms look the same. I have posted a question to the MSDN forums to try and get an answer. If interested, you can follow the discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7aff3552-994f-473a-9338-69aff947befd/code-analysis-failures-during-build?forum=vsdebug

Answer (score 0):

Did you restore Nuget Packages before trying to build?
If you are using **[Visual Studio Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/visual-studio-build)** task (or **[MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/msbuild)**), you can check the option "Restore Nuget Packages"

The prefered option is to add a **[Nuget Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget)** task before your build task. Simply point to your Sln (***.sln) and it will do the job.